# Is there a way to attach an error handler to bash scripts?

Tags: bash, error-handling

Is there a way to add an error handler to bash, which executes if any given command in the script fails?

I'm aware of `set -o errexit`, but that doesn't allow me to add a custom error handler.

Comment: You should take a look at the `trap` command.

Answer (score 3):

```
set -e
trap "do your custom stuff here" EXIT
...
# now whenever there's an error condition, due to the set -e, the script will exit
# and upon this exit, the trap custom message shall be activated.
```

Comment: Or use the `ERR` trap.

Comment: But will that work if we are exiting from a function?

Comment: See the manual and the `errtrace` option